# How to access a file from aspx web page ie \\folder\\mydocument.doc

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to access a word document by applying the following to the explorer navigation bar

\folder\subfolder\mydocument.doc

I am not looking to read the content and load the aspx page, just access the file and let the person's PC use word to open it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: So you want a website to allow a downloading of a document on the server to a browser, and let the user open the file after it has been downloaded locally?

Comment: Is the file in a location that the user can access?  If so, just providing a link to it should do the trick, no?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide the user with a link to a file which they have access to through their local file system, you can use the 'file://' prefix on your URL.

I just tried this in an HTML file...

```
<a href="file://c:\temp\test.docx">Open File</a>
```

... and tested it in IE and Chrome on my PC and it worked fine.

Hope that's what you're after?!

Answer (score 0):

Add a hyperlink like that in your page:

```
<asp:Hyperlink ID="hpMyLink" runat="server" />
```

In you code, where it belong (Page_Load, Item_DataBound, etc), you must fix the needed URL with something similar to that :

```
hpMyLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", _YOURWEBSERVERROOT, relativeFilePath);
```

**- or -**

if user will always access it from the same place of you site, simply do

```
hpMyLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("/folder/subfolder/{1}", fileName);
```

This will cause the user navigator uploading the document.

**Note** : FYI, depending of what you want to do and which user have access to this file, you must consider that fact that not all user have access to open a .doc file (MAC user, Mobile user, etc). Something else may be consider like PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You may need the [WebDAV](http://www.iis.net/download/webdav)

...

[How to configure WebDAV](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/did-you-know-configure-webdav-in-iis-7-75.aspx)